# Ubuntu Installation on Qemu/KVM Black Screen

Tags: kvm-virtualization, qemu

I'm trying to install **Ubuntu** or higher on **KVM**.

I have tried installing **14.04.6 LTS** / **16.04.7 LTS** and **18.04.5 LTS**

First i create **Qemu Disk Image** :

```
qemu-img.exe create -f raw hdd.img 5G
```

and when i boot to the **ISO** :

[image]

after selecting **Install Ubuntu Server** it shows a **black screen** and stuck there.

i also tried to set **nomodeset** by pressing **F6** *(Other Options)* and marking **x** on **nomodeset**

it's also showing a **black screen**.

[image]

*Note :* it's not rebooting itself, it's just stuck at black screen.

*(only for testing on KVM)* i had successfully installed **Ubuntu 11.04-desktop-i386 (Natty Narwhal)** but it's support has ended and became too old and once i ran some updates with difficulty and rebooted, it didn't boot at all *(hanging on blank screen with loading spinner at bottom right)*.

So to install any newer version of *server/desktop* if possible on this **KVM**.

Here's a **BIOS** boot information :

[image]

I'm running this **KVM** on **RouterOS v5.25** (mikrotik) so i can't update anything individually, i have to upgrade the whole RouterOS and i'm not capable to do that at this moment. i'm not even sure if i upgraded the RotuerOS to newer version it will work, maybe it's currently working but all i need is to set or configure soemthing to make it boot.

Here's **RouterOS** configuration :

[image]

```
Host CPU : Intel E8600 with VT-x enabled in (Host machine BIOS)
Host Memory : 4GB
Virutal Machine CPU count : 2
Virutal Machine Memory : 1024M
```

What causes this problem?

Comment: Only supported releases of Ubuntu (*standard support*) are on-topic for this site.  Ubuntu 14.04 LTS is in extended support and now Ubuntu 14.04 ESM thus only supported by Canonical via Ubuntu Advantage thus also off-topic here.  Refer https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EOLUpgrades http://fridge.ubuntu.com/2019/05/02/ubuntu-14-04-trusty-tahr-reached-end-of-life-on-april-25-2019-esm-available/

Comment: is there anything else?